# When putting an Outlet in Xcode into a variable, don't know what kind of pointer to use?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So I was going through Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X for Dummies by Erick Tejkowski. After doing the calculator example, I got the basics of Objective-C in Xcode, since I know basic stuff. I got that to put what's in a text field into a variable, you first have to put the text field as an outlet in the header file like this:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Mah_Application__It_is_awesomeAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{

    NSWindow *window;
    IBOutlet id hi;

}
- (IBAction)Calculate:(id)sender;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

And then you put it in a variable like so:

```
- (IBAction)Calculate:(id)sender
{

    int something;
    hi = [hi intValue];

}
```

However, when I want a Boolean value, like a checkbox or something, or perhaps even a radio group, I don't know what pointer to use in place of intValue. For a moment, assume the variable hi is now a boolean. I tried this:

```
- (IBAction)Calcluate:(id)sender
{

    BOOL something;
    something = [hi BOOL];

}
```

but it says that's not a valid pointer. What should I use, then?

Answer (score 1):

`boolValue` is defined for NSString and NSNumber, so it depends on what type `hi` is

```
- (IBAction)Calcluate:(id)sender
{
    BOOL something = [hi boolValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit (I re-read the question and you might want what the other answer from Stew suggested):**

```
BOOL myBool = [@"1" boolValue];
myBool = [someObject boolValue];
```

These are some of the conversion methods for NSString - Also see the [NSString Reference Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html):

```
- (double)doubleValue;
- (float)floatValue;
- (int)intValue;
- (NSInteger)integerValue;
- (long long)longLongValue;

// (boolValue) Skips initial space characters (whitespaceSet), 
// or optional -/+ sign followed by zeroes. 
// Returns YES on encountering one of "Y", "y", "T", "t", or a digit 1-9. 
// It ignores any trailing characters.
- (BOOL)boolValue;
```

Also, from [NSNumber Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/boolValue):

> boolValue Returns the receiver’s value as a BOOL.
>
> `- (BOOL)boolValue`
>
> Return Value The receiver’s value as a BOOL,
>   converting it as necessary.
>
> Special Considerations Prior to Mac OS X v10.3, the value returned
>   isn’t guaranteed to be one of YES or NO. A 0 value always means NO or
>   false, but any nonzero value should be interpreted as YES or true.

---

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.25]
// etc...

- (IBAction)Calcluate:(id)sender
{

    BOOL something;
    something = [hi [NSNumber numberWithBool:BOOL]];

}
```

[NSNumber reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Since things like `BOOL`, `NSInteger`, `NSUInteger`, etc are not pointers, they cannot do certain things like be values for a dictionary, etc.  For this purpose, NSNumber was created.  It wraps these types in a class so they can be used as arguments for passing to `selectors`, or stored in `NSDictionary`'s.

Here is a common thing I do:

```
[self.myLoadingView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] waitUntilDone:YES];
```